# How to connect internet across a static IP network?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, dhcp, ip, static-ip

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 but without internet *at home*.
The reason I think is *I have changed my network connections recently to static IP* from DHCP because `gnuradio` needs `static IP` for accessing external hardware.
Since then it works in college and I can't access internet at home.

My `ifconfig eth0` result comes like below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:4d:a2:86:5f:0c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:28 Base address:0xa000
```

My `cat /etc/network/interfaces` output comes like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

How can I make it work at home with static IP?

Comment: What happens if you enter `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1` in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your home internet does not use 192.168.1.*. You could change the configuration on your router to use 192.168.1.* addresses. You should check the user manual for your router to learn how to do this.